# Embedding ipython qt-console as qwidget inside qt/c++ application

Tags: c++, qt, boost, ipython

Is there some example of people embedding ipython-qt console inside their C++/Qt application?
I've only seen examples of people embedding that in PyQt applications.

What I would like to do is at the end something like the console example available for PythonQt, where from a console with autocompletition, one can modify internal status of c++ variables.

Maybe is it possible thanks to an additional layer of binding of C++ methods via Boost.Python?

Comment: I think it's possible, but I don't know that anyone has done it. You'll need to [embed a Python interpreter](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) in your application as well as wrapping the C++ classes to expose them to Python.

Comment: The wrapping of C++ classes was possible with the help of PythonQt library: 
http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/
The same library provided an elementary shell, but I want more, I would like to integrate the IPython-Qt shell as widget....

Comment: Neat, I've not come across PythonQt before. As far as I know, you're the first person to investigate this, and I'd be fascinated to know whether it works out. I think the starting point would be to adapt [this example](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/lib/ipkernel_qtapp.py) of running an IPython kernel inside a PyQt app with C++ using PythonQt.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking to try and do something similar.  I'm trying to at the very least use the ipython kernel in a c++ widget.  So far the only stuff I have found online is importing modules into python.  I have found nothing on the ipython github site either yet.  But I'm still digging.